# og:image from Digital Ocean space/Amazon S3 could not be processed as an image because it has an invalid content type

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, facebook-opengraph, digital-ocean

I am building a website where a user can upload a cover image. The cover image will then be resized and upload to Digital Ocean Space. What happens after that is I will then use the resized version (1200*627) as the `og:image`. This is what the header looks like after Facebook scraped it.

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://sgp1.digitaloceanspaces.com/hologram-develop/__sized__/staging/businesscard/cover/1/7fd5f9ef-d9fe-4fb1-a835-b4aab37532f5-crop-c0-5__0-5-1200x627-70.jpg?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=PCOBIQX2EC5XUDKEYJ2N%2F20200917%2Fsgp1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20200917T031717Z&X-Amz-Expires=3600&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=36544132bfb2d81d2a4189ed29dd9ec8aad70a5c67875372956e51ec978cb2d8" />
```

However, I am getting below error:

```
Provided og:image URL, https://sgp1.digitaloceanspaces.com/hologram-develop/__sized__/staging/businesscard/cover/1/7fd5f9ef-d9fe-4fb1-a835-b4aab37532f5-crop-c0-5__0-5-1200x627-70.jpg?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=PCOBIQX2EC5XUDKEYJ2N%2F20200917%2Fsgp1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20200917T031717Z&X-Amz-Expires=3600&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=36544132bfb2d81d2a4189ed29dd9ec8aad70a5c67875372956e51ec978cb2d8 could not be processed as an image because it has an invalid content type.
```

Upon closer inspection, the content type is correct when I try to access the URL, which is `image/jpeg`.

[image: network inspection]

I had seen [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57662726/provided-ogimage-url-url-to-aws-s3-could-not-be-processed-as-an-image-becaus) which the person place the private link without the credential which causes the problem. However, it is not quite the same for my case as my URL include the credential to the bucket.

The problem is also not due to the image size. The size is 1200*627, which is the recommended size of Facebook. Does Facebook only take in Public image URL? Or do I need to do anything extra for it to works?

Comment: Maybe facebook strips the query parameters? Also, are you sure using a signed URL that expires in 3600 seconds is the best way to do this?

Comment: I am indeed not sure if Facebook does strip the query parameter. For the latter, every single time a request is made, the image URL is being generated, and I think it is safe to assume that social preview debugger is able to process the image within 3600 seconds.